# smarty escape single quote in if else condition

Tags: smarty, escaping

need some help from smarty expert.
I am new in smarty template engine.

I would like to escape a single quote in a string, how can I do that
inside my .tpl

I got a if else condition

```
$current_category.category eq 'King's Tea'
```

the problem is the 'King's Tea' , that is my category name, 
I tried 'King\'s Tea' , Smarty can't convert it

I tried {litereal}'King's Tea'{/litereal}, this one doesn't work in if else condition.

is there any way I can escape the single quote?

I tried to search in smarty API side. the escape page, just tell us how to escape from the variable.

Comment: I got the solution, actually I use double quote for the string then it will auto escape.

Comment: 'King's Tea'  =>  "King's Tea"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$current_category.category eq "King's Tea"

Comment: How about if you have both single and double quotes in the same text? i.e. `$current_category.category eq "King`s "Tea""`?